# Differences bewteen time consumed of python loops

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, time-complexity

I am running a program and it really consumes a lot of time for a 3-layers loop. I reduced the size of loop and observed an interesting thing.

**When the first layer is 50 iterations,** it only comsumes 3 seconds. **But when I changed it to 100 iterations**, the time increased to 43 seconds. Why the time spent not doubled when the number of iterations just doubled? How the calculation complexity was calculted... I dont understand.

By the way my original designed loop was `160x192x160`. It spent really a lot of time and I just stopped it. I think I need to figure out one way to solve this time problem. This is why I tried above mentioned.

```
start=time.time()
choice_list=[]
result_list=[]
mean_list=[]
point_info=[]
patch_radius=patch_radius
for k in range (0,50):
    for l in range (0,100):
        for h in range (0,10):
            if img[k][l][h]!=0:
               mean=patch_mean(coordinate_x=k,coordinate_y=l,coordinate_z=h,image=img,patch_radius=patch_radius)
               point_info=[k,l,h,mean]
               mean_list.append(point_info)
end=time.time()
print(end-start)
```

`patch_mean` is a function calculated the mean around a point. It is another loop. I think it would not matter. Because it is an independent fucntion. To be clear, patch raidus is a constant

```
def patch_mean(coordinate_x,coordinate_y,coordinate_z,image,patch_radius):
    sum=0
    count=0
    for k in range(coordinate_x- patch_radius, coordinate_x + patch_radius):
        for l in range(coordinate_y - patch_radius, coordinate_y + patch_radius):
            for h in range (coordinate_z - patch_radius, coordinate_z + patch_radius):
              if 0<k<159 and 0<l<191 and 0<h<159:
                 if img[k][l][h] != 0:
                   sum = sum + img[k][l][h]
                   count = count + 1
    if count==0:
        mean=0
    else:
        mean=sum/count
    return mean
```

Comment: Create a simple loop that runs for `10**4` iterations and time it. Do it again for `10**5` iterations. Would you expect the second approach to take 10x longer?

Comment: the number increased 10 times larger right? Why not expect 10 times larger?

Comment: it will double the time if you do a simple calculation inside the nested for loop, but it also depends on your `patch_mean`  function where it consumes any computation.

Comment: why patch_mean will matter? it is an independent part and will run once an iteration right? Iteration number doubled but time increased 10 times longer?...

Comment: what is `patch_radius` ? Where do the number 159, 191 and 159 come from in the condition in the function `patch_mean`. Did you change them when changing k range ?

Comment: patch_radius is a constant

Comment: I know, but if it's big it could matter. And where does the three number comes from ? Do you change them when changing the k range ?

Comment: I dont change anything but just first interation number from 50 to 100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246728/discussion-between-alois-christen-and-bigbo).

Answer (score 1):

The first iterations of your outer loop give you coordinates that are near boundary of your image. That makes the `patch_mean` faster to calculate, as a big chunk of its area is cut off. When you move towards the middle of the image, the computation will be slower, since you'll be able to get an average of the whole patch area, not just a part of it.

If you change the range from `range(0, 50)` to `range(0, 100)`, you're will be a lot more of the middle part of the image. Those coordinates are the slow ones, so overall, the loop will be a lot slower. If you changed it to `range(0, 160)`, you'd find that the last few iterations would speed up again, as you'd start running into the *other* side of the image. But the interval from 50-100 is right in the middle of the image, and will be the slowest part.

Comment: I think you are right. that is the thing I found as well. Is there a way to make the computation faster? I mean the whole interation 160*192*160 will take long time to run. Should I use gpu to spped up or any other way?